# Displaying preference activity in a tab

Tags: android, tabs, preferenceactivity

I have three tabs . I have added functionalities to the first two tabs . Now , I wish to use the third tab to display the settings / preferences so that the user can choose from a list of various settings. I wish to use Preference Activity to do the same . Is it possible to do so ? If yes , how ? If no , what are the alternate option I can use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution . As MisterSquonk stated, I added a preference activity as an intent to the settings tab . I then created a dynamic preference layout in the activity. Shall try the fragments approach too - Thanks Stefan and MisterSquonk !!

Answer (score 2):

To set a tab's content to an `Avtivity` you need to create an explicit `Intent` and pass it in the `TabHost.TabSpec.setContent(Intent intent)` method.

Something like this should work...

```
// This code assumes tabHost is a reference to your TabHost widget
// and that you have created the tag and indicator variables

TabHost.TabSpec spec;
Intent intent;

intent = new Intent(this, MyPreferenceActivity.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(indicator).setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this solution:

Create a TabHost based on Fragments, i.e. each tab displays one Fragment. Then use a PreferenceFragment for one of your tabs.